# I have question about SSAT words' analogies

Tags: analogy

I have questions about some words' relationships

1. **anthem** is to **inspire** as **ape** is to **copy**. My question is that why is not to **shuttle** is to **transport**.
2. **actor** is to **script** as **musician** is to **score**. Why is not to **student** is to **textbook.**
3. **rocket** is to **torpedo** as **air** is to **water**. Why is not to **explosion** is to **hole**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one doesn't work for me.  "an anthem inspires people" but an ape doesn't copy people.  "To ape is to copy".  Whereas "A shuttle is a type of transport".

The second works better:  An actor performs a script. A musician performs a score.  But a student doesn't perform a textbook.

A rocket goes through the air, a torpedo goes through the water, but a hole doesn't go through the water.

Comment: Obviously apes _were_ considered to copy people, since 'to ape' has come to mean 'to imitate' - but I agree that the supposed analogy with anthems is very odd.

Comment: A shuttle is a particular form of transport, a ship, train, bus, plane, etc, that travels regularly (and also maybe often) between the same two places, often quite close together. Originally a part of a loom which travels back and forth regularly between two fixed points.

Comment: Surely these are riddles. So with the first one it could be that "shuttles transport people" and "transports shuttle people" are both true. Whereas you can't say "inspires anthem people" or "copies ape people".